# Change first element of each group in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to ensure that the first value of `val2` corresponding to each `vintage` is `NaN`. Currently two are already `NaN`, but I want to ensure that `0.53` also changes to `NaN`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'vintage': ['2017-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01'],
        'date': ['2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-03-01'],
        'val1': [0.59, 0.68, 0.8, 0.54, 0.61, 0.6],
        'val2': [np.nan, 0.66, 0.81, 0.53, 0.62, np.nan]
    })
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
df.groupby('vintage').first().val2 #This gives the first non-NaN values, as shown below

vintage
2017-01-01    0.66
2017-02-01    0.53
2017-03-01     NaN

df.groupby('vintage').first().val2 = np.nan #This doesn't change anything
df.val2

0     NaN
1    0.66
2    0.81
3    0.53
4    0.62
5     NaN
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't assign to the result of an aggregation, also `first` ignores existing `NaN`, what you can do is call `head(1)` which will return the first row for each group, and pass the indices to `loc` to mask the orig df to overwrite those column values:

```
In[91]
df.loc[df.groupby('vintage')['val2'].head(1).index, 'val2'] = np.NaN
df:

Out[91]: 
         date  val1  val2     vintage
0  2017-01-01  0.59   NaN  2017-01-01
1  2017-02-01  0.68  0.66  2017-01-01
2  2017-03-01  0.80  0.81  2017-01-01
3  2017-02-01  0.54   NaN  2017-02-01
4  2017-03-01  0.61  0.62  2017-02-01
5  2017-03-01  0.60   NaN  2017-03-01
```

here you can see that `head(1)` returns the first row for each group:

```
In[94]:
df.groupby('vintage')['val2'].head(1)
Out[94]: 
0     NaN
3    0.53
5     NaN
Name: val2, dtype: float64
```

contrast with `first` which will return the first non-NaN unless there is only `NaN` values for that group:

```
In[95]:
df.groupby('vintage')['val2'].first()

Out[95]: 
vintage
2017-01-01    0.66
2017-02-01    0.53
2017-03-01     NaN
Name: val2, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

Or create the Position , pick the first one , change val2 to `np.nan`

```
df.loc[df.groupby('vintage').vintage.cumcount()==0,'val2']=np.nan
df
Out[154]: 
         date  val1  val2     vintage
0  2017-01-01  0.59   NaN  2017-01-01
1  2017-02-01  0.68  0.66  2017-01-01
2  2017-03-01  0.80  0.81  2017-01-01
3  2017-02-01  0.54   NaN  2017-02-01
4  2017-03-01  0.61  0.62  2017-02-01
5  2017-03-01  0.60   NaN  2017-03-01
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could also write:

```py
def h(x):
 x['val2'].iloc[0] = np.NaN
 return x

df = df.groupby("vintage").apply(h)
```

Answer (score 1):

Timings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'vintage': ['2017-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01'],
        'date': ['2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-03-01'],
        'val1': [0.59, 0.68, 0.8, 0.54, 0.61, 0.6],
        'val2': [np.nan, 0.66, 0.81, 0.53, 0.62, np.nan]
    })

def BENY(df):
    df.loc[df.groupby('vintage').vintage.cumcount() == 0, 'val2'] = np.nan
    
def EdChum(df):
    df.loc[df.groupby('vintage')['val2'].head(1).index, 'val2'] = np.nan
    
def knoble(df):
    def func(x):
        x['val2'].iloc[0] = np.nan
        return x
    df.groupby("vintage", group_keys=False).apply(func)

%timeit BENY(df)
406 µs ± 4.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
%timeit EdChum(df)
454 µs ± 1.28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
%timeit knoble(df)
1.07 ms ± 5.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```