# Efficient use of numpy select

Tags: python, pandas, select

I have some data as follows. I'm trying to compute the values in the `Time bw` column (it should be 0 in the 4th row). Whenever the `Location` moves to a new one, like `a` to `b`, I want the `Time bw` to restart from 0. I'm trying to use `ne` ,`select` and `diff()`

```
+----------+---------------------+----------+
| Location |         Date        | Time bw  |
+----------+---------------------+----------+
| a        | 2018-06-26 00:00:00 |        0 |
| a        | 2018-06-26 00:00:00 |        0 |
| a        | 2018-06-26 00:00:00 |        0 |
| b        | 2018-08-03 00:00:00 |       38 |
| b        | 2018-08-03 00:00:00 |        0 |
| b        | 2018-08-04 00:00:00 |        1 |
| b        | 2018-08-04 00:00:00 |        0 |
| b        | 2018-08-04 00:00:00 |        0 |
| b        | 2018-08-04 00:00:00 |        0 |
| b        | 2018-08-04 00:00:00 |        0 |
| b        | 2018-08-04 00:00:00 |        0 |
| b        | 2018-08-05 00:00:00 |        1 |
| b        | 2018-08-08 00:00:00 |        3 |
| b        | 2018-08-08 00:00:00 |        0 |
| b        | 2018-08-08 00:00:00 |        0 |
| b        | 2018-08-08 00:00:00 |        0 |
| b        | 2018-08-08 00:00:00 |        0 |
| c        | 2018-08-14 00:00:00 |        6 |
| c        | 2018-08-14 00:00:00 |        0 |
| c        | 2018-08-14 00:00:00 |        0 |
+----------+---------------------+----------+
```

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: ```df['Time'] = df.groupby('Location')['Date'].diff()```?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change first element of each group in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46242488/change-first-element-of-each-group-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df['Time bw'] = np.where(df.Location.ne(df.Location.shift()), 0, df['Time bw'])
```

output:

```
    Location    Date    Time bw
0   a   20180626 00:00:00   0
1   a   20180626 00:00:00   0
2   a   20180626 00:00:00   0
3   b   20180803 00:00:00   0
4   b   20180803 00:00:00   0
5   b   20180804 00:00:00   1
6   b   20180804 00:00:00   0
7   b   20180804 00:00:00   0
8   b   20180804 00:00:00   0
9   b   20180804 00:00:00   0
10  b   20180804 00:00:00   0
11  b   20180805 00:00:00   1
12  b   20180808 00:00:00   3
13  b   20180808 00:00:00   0
14  b   20180808 00:00:00   0
15  b   20180808 00:00:00   0
16  b   20180808 00:00:00   0
17  c   20180814 00:00:00   0
18  c   20180814 00:00:00   0
19  c   20180814 00:00:00   0
```

Comment: The kind of thing we can do with one-liners, it's crazy!

Comment: A simple straight assign through `loc` also works:   `df.loc[df.Location.ne(df.Location.shift()), 'Time bw'] = 0`